# Insert item into active tab pane

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I currently have a tabbed interface using Twitter bootstrap tabs. I need to be able to click a button in order to insert an item into the currently active tab pane using conventional meteor methods. I've ventured in several different possible solutions, but I haven't been able to find the correct one.

My first thought was to think of it like inserting a comment into a post. However, the way I'm working with it, the page that lists the items is, of course, a bootstrap tab pane. Because of this, I don't have it routed in Iron Router to a "post page" like several examples of the post-comment interface.

Any generic example of this sort of interface working would be great, since I've been stumped on this for quite some time.

**EDIT:**
Here is the template code I've been using so far:

board.html

```
<template name="board">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="board tab-pane fade" id="{{slug}}">
        {{#each jobs}}
            {{> job}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

board.coffee

```
############################################################################
# Boards
############################################################################

###
# Events
###





###
# Helpers
###

Template.board.helpers
    jobs: ->
        Jobs.find()
```

job.html

```
<template name="job">
    <div id="{{_id}}" class="job">
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: 1) Is the item a document in a collection? 2) Can more than one item be inserted into the tab pane? 3) Can you show your template code so far?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Yes, the idea is that the user will be able to click a simple button and add a "job" to a "board". This can be done as many times as needed. The template code has been added to an edited section of my post above.

Answer (score 1):

ok, all you need is an event handler that catches the button click and inserts a `job` document into the `Jobs` collection.

```
Template.mytemplate.events({ // whatever template your button is in
  'button click': function(ev){
    Jobs.insert({name: "foo"}); // however you're defining a job
  })
});
```

Since you're iterating over a cursor of `Jobs` your helper will automatically react to the new document being inserted and your DOM will automatically update.